# Trying to convert JSON to dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I scraped a website for the application/ld+json and it returns json, and I want to convert the string to a python dictionary and it doesn't seem to be working. In the terminal i get the error JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None. I'm relatively new to working with JSON so I might have made a dumb mistake, but everything I found on stack overflow didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you for taking the time to read my post!

Here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

source = requests.get('https://www.visionlearning.com/en/library/Chemistry/1/Nuclear-Chemistry/59').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

jsonString = str(soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')[0])
print(json.loads(jsonString))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you print out jsonString you will see it includes the `<script>` tab, just get the inside content:

```
jsonString = str(soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')[0].text)
```

Comment: Do I need to import a library for this because when I print(jsonString) it just return an empty line (no error messages)

Comment: No you don't need extra library. If your jsonString is empty, try print out the soup see if it can get the website content correctly. Because I just ran it again and it works fine.

Comment: Yes when I print the soup its return the data, but it does have the scripts tags which I assume the .text gets rid of. Also when I type the .text VS code does not show it as recommended syntax (hope that made sense)

Comment: I guess we are using different version of beautifulsoup then. Use `.string` instead of `.text`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = json.loads(soup.find("script").text)
    print(target.keys())


main("https://www.visionlearning.com/en/library/Chemistry/1/Nuclear-Chemistry/59")
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['@context', '@type', 'mainEntityOfPage', 'name', 'headline', 'author', 'datePublished', 'dateModified', 'image', 'publisher', 'description', 'keywords', 'inLanguage', 'copyrightHolder', 'copyrightYear'])
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same error message JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None. Did I forget to import a install something?

Comment: @Filtered which Python version you are using ?

Comment: 3.8.2 ---------

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting the first value. You don’t have to use `.find_all`. `.find` will return the first value. Turn it to string with `.get_text` or `.text` then cast it to json.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

source = requests.get('https://www.visionlearning.com/en/library/Chemistry/1/Nuclear-Chemistry/59').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

jsonString = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')

print(json.loads(jsonString.get_text(strip=True)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked I added .contents[0] to the end of jsonString

```
source = requests.get('https://www.visionlearning.com/en/library/Chemistry/1/Nuclear-Chemistry/59')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')

jsonString = soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')[0].contents[0]
print(json.loads(jsonString))
```

Thank you for all the help though!